# django haystack faceted search redirect if found an exact match with a property

Tags: django, django-haystack

I have a requirement to redirect the user to a detail page if there is an exact match on the name property of the shop model. In case of any other property, it should just take to search results page irrespective of a direct match or not.

I am currently using a `FacetedSearchCustomView` that overrides buid_page, `create_reponse` and `extra_content` methods.But I cant find a way to look inside the results of the query as query._results is protected.

Any suggestions on how to go about doing this.

Thanks

UPDATED

FacetedSearchCustomView.py

```
class FacetedSearchCustomView(FacetedSearchView):
"""
Overrides various default methods to allow for additional context, smoother UX for faceting
"""

def build_page(self):
    """
    Paginates the results appropriately.

    Overriden to redirect to page 1 if a page_no is not found
    """
    try:
        page_no = int(self.request.GET.get('page', 1))
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        raise Http404("Not a valid number for page.")

    if page_no < 1:
        raise Http404("Pages should be 1 or greater.")

    paginator = NamedPaginator(self.results, on="brand", per_page=self.results_per_page)
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    try:
        page = paginator.page(page_no)
    except InvalidPage:
        # Redirect to page 1 of the
        path = self.request.path
        qs = self.request.GET.copy()
        qs['page'] = 1
        url = '%s?%s' % (path, qs.urlencode())
        return redirect(url)

    return paginator, page

def clean_filters(self):
    """Returns a list of tuples (filter, value) of applied facets"""
    filters = []
    # get distinct facets
    facets = list(set(self.form.selected_facets))
    for facet in facets:
        if ":" not in facet:
            continue
        field, value = facet.split(":", 1)
        field = field.replace('_', ' ').replace('exact', '').title()
        filters.append((field, value))
    return filters

def create_response(self):
    """
    Generates the actual HttpResponse to send back to the user.

    Overriding to allow the redirect to pass through from overriden build_page
    """
    try:
        (paginator, page) = self.build_page()
    except ValueError:
        return self.build_page()

    context = {
        'query': self.query,
        'form': self.form,
        'page': page,
        'paginator': paginator,
        'suggestion': None,
    }

    if self.results and hasattr(self.results, 'query') and self.results.query.backend.include_spelling:
        context['suggestion'] = self.form.get_suggestion()

    context.update(self.extra_context())
    return render_to_response(self.template, context, context_instance=self.context_class(self.request))

def extra_context(self):
    extra = super(FacetedSearchCustomView, self).extra_context()
    extra['filters'] = self.clean_filters()
    if not self.results:
        extra['facets'] = self.form.search().facet_counts()
    else:
        extra['facets'] = self.results.facet_counts()

    model_type = self.request.path.split('/')[1].rstrip('s')
    extra['model_type'] = None if model_type == "search" else model_type

    # if model_type in ['package', 'project']:
    # extra['facets'] = self.clean_facets(extra['facets'])
    #     extra['model_create'] = '%s_create' % model_type
    return extra
```

CustomSearchForm.py

```
class CustomSearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

def search(self):
    sqs = super(CustomSearchForm, self).search()

    # We need to process each facet to ensure that the field name and the
    # value are quoted correctly and separately:
    for facet in self.selected_facets:
        if ":" not in facet:
            continue

        field, value = facet.split(":", 1)

        if value:
            sqs = sqs.narrow(u'%s:"%s"' % (field, sqs.query.clean(value)))

    return sqs
```

Comment: Can we see the codeyou havealready written?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something like this in the past by looking at `SearchQuerySet.best_match` and then comparing the name.

http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#SearchQuerySet.best_match